# iOS UIBarButtons don't set enabled by UIActionSheet iOS 6.1

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have three `UIBarButtons` on a `UIToolbar`. these buttons are set enabled to `YES` or `NO` depending on the state of the app.

at very moment, an `UIActionSheet` appears and ask to restart again, if user answer Ok, then the `UIBarButtons` should set enabled to YES.

It happens that the `UIActionSheet` disappears and the `UIBarButtons` show themselves as not enabled, but actually if you press them, works fine. Of course it confuses the user because the `UIBarButtons` appears like they are not enabled.

I'm working on `Xcode 5.1`, the app was built to run on `iOS 7` and `iOS 6.1`. It works perfectly running on `iOS 7`, but on `iOS 6.1`, happens what I described above.

is it a kind of refresh problem with the `UIBarButtons`? is how to iOS 6.1 handle `UIActionSheet` different than `iOS 7`?

I appreciate your directives. thanks in advance.

Heriberto Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug in iOS 6. How I get it to work was by hiding and showing the toolbar without animation to force the refresh:

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:NO];                    
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

This forces the toolbar to redraw.

Comment: Thanks a lot reecon, I understand now it's a bug, and I understand the solution is to refresh the toolbar. I have been testing your suggestion, however now it appears two toolbars, one gray and up above the right one. I'll playing with this. thanks again.